# Python urlencode is loosing data when encoding utf-8

Tags: php, python, encoding, utf-8, urlencode

I have a simple urlencode to push data from my python to my php file.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import urllib,urllib2
    array={'test':'Ch\xe2teau'}
    test=urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('http://localhost/link/php.php',urllib.urlencode(array,True))).read()
    print test
```

The array is utf-8 encoded. I am trying to pass to to my php file for use but it turns into a `?`

Here is my result:

[image]

How can I prevent this data loss?

Comment: Unicode characters are not valid in URI's ( only ascii ) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2
Not sure why the function isn't replacing it with 'a', haven't check the source of urllib2

Comment: Your string is not a valid utf8, if you want the utf8 for the unicode 00E2 then you should do `array={'test':'Ch\xc3\xa2teau'}`